# MySQL Gives results for every row in JOINed table

Tags: mysql, join, max

I have been trying to perform a query with a JOIN to enhance performance.
Currently, one query would be done to retrieve all records, then for each record another query is performed to grab the specific step completed.

I have two tables, that look like this:

Users:

```
id - name - email
------------------
1 - alex - a@b.com
```

Steps:

```
id - userId - step - date
-------------------------------
1  -   1    -   1  - 2018/01/01
2  -   1    -   2  - 2018/02/02
3  -   1    -   3  - 2018/03/03
```

Now the query I use to grab all users and their respective steps is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, s.step, s.date
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN steps s ON s.userId = u.id
```

But this would return:

```
id - name - step - date
-------------------------------
1  -  alex  -   1  - 2018/01/01
2  -  alex  -   2  - 2018/02/02
3  -  alex  -   3  - 2018/03/03
```

And I am only interested in the last result, I believe I should be using a subquery perhaps of some kind? And the MAX(s.date) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct

```
Where steps.id IN (select 
MAX(id) from 
steps group by user userid)
```

This assumes your MAX(id) in steps will always be the greatest date.

Comment: Do I add this to the bottom of my existing query?

Comment: Yes. Add to the bottom

Comment: Thanks, sorry I got caught up in something else. But I managed to get it working!